# Make tuple of sets in Python

Tags: python, set, tuples

I want to put two sets in a tuple in Python.

```
set1 = set(1, 2, 3, 4)
set2 = set(5, 6, 7)
```

What I've tried:

```
result = tuple(set1, set2)
# got error "TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2"
```

Desired output:

```
({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7})
```

Comment: Well, before that you will get `TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 4`. This is not how `set()` or `tuple()` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple literal is just values separated by commas.

```
set1 = {1,2,3,4}
set2 = {5,6,7}
result = set1, set2
```

or if you find it clearer

```
result = (set1, set2)
```

The `tuple(x)` form is useful when you have an iterable sequence `x` that you want to transform to a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

`set` and `tuple` constructors take only one argument: an iterable. Wrap your arguments in a list and it should work.

```
set1 = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
set2 = set([5, 6, 7])
result = tuple([set1, set2])  # or (set1, set2)
print(result)  # ({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7})
```

Comment: Using `tuple(...)` is unnecessary when you're putting in explicit values.

Comment: @khelwood Hmm you're right